# (done) Reopen "How to discipline uncooperative senior engineers after new laptops forced on them"

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

The question [How to discipline uncooperative senior engineers after new laptops forced on them](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/104892/how-to-discipline-uncooperative-senior-engineers-after-new-laptops-forced-on-the) was closed for "requiring a goal we can address". The goal in the question is pretty clearly state - to get the senior engineers to follow the new standard and get back to being productive.

Clearly the computer configuration mandate and the OP's attitude are controversial and creating a lot of debate (much of it off-topic). That doesn't change that the question being posed is clear and answerable.

**I am requesting that this question be reopened.**

Comment: Just for the record, I had voted to close the question as off topic because I strongly suspected it to be a troll, and not for the stated close reason. For some strange reason, my comment with the close reason has now been deleted from the question.

Answer (score 2):

I put the 5th CV on it because to me it feels like a classic XY problem and is only going to invite arguments about the XY aspects.

There isn't enough information provided in the OP either to really answer it because any meaningful answer, given the... questionable choice to make the decision in the first place will *require* more information about the OP's company to answer.

To me this question is like someone asking, "How do I discipline my employees for not flying?" -- without knowing why they are expected to fly, it's not really an answerable question without a lot more context.

---

Frankly the question reads like trolling to me, though there are enough dumb companies out there that it's hard to categorically call trolling..

Comment: Even if it isn't an XY, the answers are certainly treating it as such. I also suspect this is less than true as I don't buy how the OP is essentially failing to manage consider the experience he would need to have to be managing a team of this size and level. I'd expect someone like that to know how to properly manage change and address this kind of behaviour.

Comment: I'll agree that the OP is incompetent and doesn't know what he's talking about, but I also think that if he had left off all of the technology specifics we wouldn't have any problem with the question. They answered the question of why - so that they could install and run necessary auditing and security software. If he hadn't mentioned Windows or Linux then no one would have a problem with that explanation. I think the OP doesn't know what he's talking about, which makes me think there *is* a valid reason for the decision that he can't explain well.

Comment: It's not our job to tell him whether the technology decision was correct or not, which most people seem to be doing. It *is* our job to say that senior devs are having issues and he's not listening to them. We should challenge the request to discipline and focus on getting everyone productive again. We should say that he needs to sit down and hear the concerns of his devs and determine whether the computer migration was actually the right decision and come up with a plan to address any of the valid concerns. Those are all workplace issues, not technology, which Philips answer addresses well.